# how to use if condition inside button tag

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, servlets

I am new to web development and facing some problem to implement a logic.

Below is my button tag

```html
<td>
  <input style="word-wrap: break-word;white-space: normal; background-color: #4CAF50;"
         type="button" name="meaning" value="<%=list.get(1) %>" 
         onclick="abc()">
</td>
```

I want to add an if-condition. If the condition is true, the color of the button should change (before I click the button).

i.e. When I navigate into a page containing that button, the bg-color of the button should be according to the if-condition.

Comment: server side code is in jsp?

Comment: Yes, it is in jsp

Comment: you can have two buttons and then choose which buttons you want to show with jstl's <c:choose>, <c:when> & <c:otherwise>

Comment: i already have 23 buttons in jsp page. so can't afford to have extra buttons. i have to add if condition on all the buttons

Comment: @jmmontero - Solution is better option for you

Comment: ok will try. thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

JSTL to the rescue:

```
<button class="${cond eq true ? 'blue' : 'green' }">Click Me</button>
```